# sql qry trickl puzzle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

DB table

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

Null    Null    Null    Null
120     Null    Null    Null
120     1       Null    Null
120     1       5       Null
120     1       5       1
```

`Declare @ColA as Int = 120`  --This can't be NULL but it can be something 1500 
which doesn't exists in db

`Declare @ColB as Int = 1`  --This can be NULL or it can be something 1500 which doesn't exists in db

`Declare @ColC as Int = 5`  --This can be NULL or it can be something 1500 which doesn't exists in db

`Declare @ColD as Int = 1`  --This can be NULL or it can be something 1500 which doesn't exists in db

--Rough draft but not working with more than one column

```
SELECT * FROM @TblA 
WHERE 
  @ColA=ColA  AND 
  ISNULL(ColB, @ColB)= @ColB AND 
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @TblA WHERE @ColA=ColA)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM @TblA 
WHERE 
  ColA IS NULL AND 
  ISNULL(ColB, @ColB)= @ColB AND 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblA WHERE @ColA=ColA)
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 120

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

120     Null    Null    Null
120     1       Null    Null
120     Null    5       3
120     1       5       Null
120     1       Null    4
120     1       5       1
120     1       5       Null
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 1259 @ColA has match in this db so get Null for ColA

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

Null    Null    Null    Null
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 120 & @ColB = 1 @ColB has match in db so get matching records for ColA & ColB

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

120     1       Null    Null
120     1       5       Null
120     1       Null    4
120     1       5       1
120     1       5       Null
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 120 & @ColB = 178 @ColB has no match in db so get matching records for ColA and Nulls for ColB since there is no ColB = 178

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

120     Null    Null    Null
120     1       Null    Null
120     Null    5       3
120     1       5       Null
120     1       Null    4
120     1       5       1
120     1       5       Null
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 120 & @ColB = 1 & ColC = 5 get matching records for ColA & ColB & ColC

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

120     1       5       Null
120     1       5       1
120     1       5       Null
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 120 & @ColB = 1 & ColC = 500 @ColC has no match in db so get matching records for ColA and ColB but not for ColC since there is no 
ColC = 500

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

120     1       Null    Null
120     1       5       Null
120     1       Null    4
120     1       5       1
120     1       5       Null
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 120 & @ColB = 1 & ColC = 5 & ColD = 1 get matching records for ColA & ColB & ColC & ColD

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

120     1       5       1
```

SQL Output --When @ColA = 120 & @ColB = 1 & ColC = 5 & @ColD = 500 then @ColD has no match in db so get matching records for ColA and ColB & ColC but not for ColD since there is no ColD = 500

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    

120     1       5       Null
120     1       5       1
120     1       5       Null
```

Possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT *

FROM @tblA

WHERE

@ColA = ColA  AND

(@ColB = ColB) AND

(@ColC = ColC)

Union

--Handles direct or wrong input values

SELECT *

FROM @tblA CPT

WHERE

@ColA = ColA and

(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tblA WHERE @ColB=ColB) and @ColB is Not NULL and @ColB = 
ColB)

Union

--Handles direct or wrong input values

SELECT *

FROM @tblA CPT

WHERE

@ColA = ColA and

(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tblA WHERE @ColC=ColC) and @ColC is Not NULL and @ColC = ColC)

Union

--Handles direct or wrong input values

SELECT *

FROM @tblA CPT

WHERE

@ColA = ColA and

```
(@ColB not in (SELECT ColB FROM @tblA) and @ColB is Not NULL and
```

ISNULL(ColB, @ColB)= @ColB)

Union

--Handles NULL input values

SELECT *

FROM @tblA CPT

WHERE

@ColA = ColA and

```
@ColB is NULL and ISNULL(ColB, @ColB)= @ColB
```